# TypeError is raised when using `abort(404)`

Tags: python, testing, nose, turbogears2

When I use `abort(status_code=404, detail='No such user', passthrough='json')`
This exception is raised:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
This is the traceback:

```
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/identity.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/i18n.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/wsgiapp.py", line 285, in _dispatch
    return controller(environ, context)
File "/home/jugger/workspace/web/ave/ave/lib/base.py", line 27, in __call__
    return TGController.__call__(self, environ, context)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/controllers/dispatcher.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self._perform_call(context)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/controllers/dispatcher.py", line 108, in _perform_call
    r = self._call(action, params, remainder=remainder, context=context)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/controllers/decoratedcontroller.py", line 125, in _call
    response = self._render_response(context, controller, output)
File "/home/jugger/.virtualenvs/ave/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tg/controllers/decoratedcontroller.py", line 220, in _render_response
    for name in exclude_names:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

This is my code:
I try to get an account that doesn't exist, so `NoResultFound` is caught and as the result `abort` must be done. but it raises the exception I mentioned above.

```
@expose('json')
def get_one(self, account_id):
    """
    Get an account

    :param account_id :type: str

    :return Account :type: dict
    """
    try:
        _id = int(account_id)
    except ValueError:
        abort(status_code=400, detail='account_id must be int', passthrough='json')
    try:
        account = DBSession.query(Account).filter(Account.id == _id).one()
    except NoResultFound:
        abort(status_code=404, detail='No such user', passthrough='json')
    return dict(
        id=account.id,
        username=account.username,
        reputation=account.reputation,
        badges=account.badges,
        created=account.created,
        bio=account.bio
    )
```

Comment: It's ok to attach images only if necessary. Providing error and log in string help's the page loading and search engines.

Comment: @pylover You are right but it would exceed the word count limit. I had no other options

Comment: You dont have to post the all call stack. it helps other users to search your post trough google.

Comment: @pylover. Good point.tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's something the authentication layer does, whenever is signaled back to the user that authentication is needed the challenger will intervene and force the user to login ( http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/turbogears/authentication.html?highlight=challenger#how-it-works-in-turbogears )

If you want to avoid that behaviour the easiest way is to use `tg.abort(401, passthrough=True)` which will skip such step, as you are talking about an API you probably want to use `passthrough='json'` which will provide a JSON response. See  http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes.html#tg.controllers.util.abort

Your response might then get caught by the `ErrorPageApplicationWrapper` depending on TurboGears version in such case make sure `ErrorController.document` has `@expose('json')` or you will face the crash you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem but there is another issue. I will edit the question and mention it.

Comment: that's odd, where are you calling the `abort`? can you provide a snippet that reproduces the issue? Abort is supposed to totally skip the rendering engine, so I can't see how you could end up in rendering a template.